# Failing at merging arrays in PHP, don't know how to do it right

Tags: php

I have the following code:

```
<?php

if (strpos($_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"], "MSIE 7") === false &&
    strpos($_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"], "MSIE 8") === false) 
{
    $styleswitcher = '<select id="themes">'."\n";
    $themes = glob('themes/*', GLOB_ONLYDIR);
    $styleswitcher .= '</select>'."\n";
    foreach ($themes as $theme) {
        include_once $theme.'/info.php';
    }
}
if(isset($_GET['icon']) && $_GET['icon'] != '') {
    $icon = $_GET['icon'];
    $icons = array();
    echo "<p class=\"lead\">".$icons[$icon]['home']."</p>";
}
?>
```

I also have the following two files in themes/fugue and themes/silk:

```
<?php
$icons = array(
    'fugue' => array(
        'home' => 'hello',
    ),
);
?>

<?php
$icons = array(
    'silk' => array(
        'home' => 'hellosies',
    ),
);
?>
```

However when running the code, it works when it is the file in themes/silk but not when it is the file in themes/fugue. I would love it if someone could be able to help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what is happening is that in the `foreach` loop you are overwriting `$icons` each time you include one of those files where `$icons` is defined. That is why it only works for the last one.

If you alter those files to instead define *specific keys* of `$icons`, like this:

```
// themes/silk/info.php
<?php
$icons['fugue'] = array('home' => 'hello');

// themes/fugue/info.php
<?php
$icons['silk'] = array('home' => 'hellosies');
```

then you should be able to avoid this problem. This way it will append to `$icons` instead of overwriting it.

Answer (score 0):

You're overwriting the $icons array each time each file is require()d. So it loads themes/fugue, which defines $icons to be: {"fugue" : { "home" : "hello" } }, and then loads themes/silk, which REPLACES $icons to become: {"silk":{"home":"hellosies"}} .

But what you want is
{ "fugue": { "home": "hello" }, "silk": { "home": "hellosies" } }

You should initialize $icons=Array() BEFORE the require()s. Then in the files do

themes/fugue:
$icons["fugue"]=Array("home" => "hello");

themes/silk:
$icons["silk"]=Array("home" => "hellosies");

It's not so much that you're trying to merge arrays, but that you're trying to add to an existing array.